# nav menu issue with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a menu in my WordPress site. The code never adds "open" on click, I don't know why.

When i click, it has another code that adds "sfHover" class in #menu-item-300.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-icon1, #nav-icon2, #nav-icon3, #nav-icon4').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-300" class="mega-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-300">
    <a>
      <div id="nav-icon1">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <span role="presentation" class="dropdown-menu-toggle" aria-expanded="false"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code works when there is some actual content in `#nav-icon1`: https://jsfiddle.net/98xewhjb/. If it doesn't work for you check for errors in the console

Comment: Maybe is because in wordpress it has a sfHover toggle class in li#menu-item-300 ?And I have no errors in console :(. The spans are a hamburger css menu.

Comment: In that case check that your `.open` class is specific enough to override any existing styles.

Comment: But the "open" class is not added.

Comment: Then there's something wrong in your HTML somewhere, or there is an error you've missed in the console.

Comment: i added the js code inside >   jQuery( function( $ ){            }); Maybe its this?

Comment: That's a document.ready event handler. Your code should be in there.

Comment: yes i know i'm desperate haha. I will try but its something about wordpress, because if i copy the entire html in codepen, it works fine with the js code for the icon. But when its in wordpress with the toggle class sfHover to make appear the menu, doesnt work my code.